# pypi information displayed in the wrong place

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pypi, distutils

After having uploaded my code to pypi using twine, the information that should be displayed in the sidebar (i.e. homepage, classifiers, keywords, author, author-email) are now displayed in the main body as plaintext (except for homepage and author-email, which are urls).

I wondered if this is an issue with my setup.py but haven't found much on google yet.

The (abridged) contents of setup.py:

```
setup(
    name="binarycpython",
    version="0.2",
    description="""
    This is a python API for binary_c (versions {}) by David Hendriks, Rob Izzard and collaborators.
    Based on the initial set up by Jeff andrews.
    It is tested and designed to work for versions {}, we can't guarantee proper functioning for other versions

    If you want to use a different version of binary_c, download and install a different version of this package
    """.format(
        ','.join(str(REQUIRED_BINARY_C_VERSIONS)), ','.join(str(REQUIRED_BINARY_C_VERSIONS))
    ),
    author="David Hendriks",
    author_email="davidhendriks93@gmail.com",
    # long_description=readme(),
    long_description="hello",
    url="https://gitlab.eps.surrey.ac.uk/ri0005/binary_c-python",
    license="gpl",
    keywords = ['binary_c', 'astrophysics', 'stellar evolution', 'population synthesis'],   # Keywords that define your package best
    packages=[
        "binarycpython",
        "binarycpython.utils",
        "binarycpython.core",
        "binarycpython.tests",
        "binarycpython.tests.c_bindings",
    ],
    install_requires=["numpy", "pytest", "h5py"],
    include_package_data=True,
    ext_modules=[BINARY_C_PYTHON_API_MODULE],  # binary_c must be loaded

    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: C",
        "Topic :: Education",
        "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Physics",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    ],

    cmdclass={'build': CustomBuildCommand},

)
```

The description is also formatted in an odd way: the lines after the blank line are in a different place than the rest. This, however, might be just the way it works.

Any suggestions/tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `description` field should not contain newlines.

This is https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1390.

Comment: This has indeed solved the issue of the wrong formatting, as well as another issue that I had with long_description being in markdown instead of rst.

Answer (score 1):

You should exchange (short) `description` and `long_description`. But other than that everything in the `setup.py` looks right. You can verify the data yourself by looking into the generated file `PKG-INFO`.

My advice is to contact PyPI support.

Comment: So the long_description contains a placeholder for what is in readme.md (I encounter a different problem there with having a markdown rather than a .rst file), so the `description` contains what I intend it to have I think. Regarding the PKG-INFO: it indeed contains the correct information (i.e. all the classifiers, homepage etc)